# F# Charting on Mac OSX issues

Tags: charts, f#

When trying to load the fsx "Fsharp.Charing.Gtk.fsx" I get the error "The assembly reference FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Settings.dll was not found or is invalid". When I #r the dll the error goes away but when I try to use Chart.Line I'm given the error, "The type referenced through 'OxyPlot.OxyColor' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'OxyPlot'" So then I referenced the OxyPlot dll as well, trying with Oxyplot.Core and OxyPlot.GtkSharp. With both the same error remains.

edit: I'm using mac osx, which is why I'm using the Gtk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to to run .fs files? It sounds like you might not have F# installed on your machine, also there is a typo in your first reference

```
Fsharp.Charing.Gtk.fsx"
```

Ought to be

```
Fsharp.Charting.Gtk.fsx"
```

And unless that fsx is in the same directory as your fsharp file, you will need to specify the path as well.

Comment: It's right in my file I just copied the name by hand into this question incorrectly. I'm using visual studio for mac. I can run F# projects. Seems unlikely F# is not installed.